# Jaxb Giving null on Unmarshalling nested Soap Message

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I need to unmarshall nested soap response to java object using jaxb. But i am always getting a null pointer exception.

I have checked almost all links out there like the following:
[jaxb unmarshalling returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425392/jaxb-unmarshalling-returns-null)
[jaxb unmarshalling giving NULL to anytype element in xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211249/jaxb-unmarshalling-giving-null-to-anytype-element-in-xsd)

But nothing worked out for me.

Here is my soap response message

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsap.org/sap/env/' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:subscribeProductResponse xmlns:ns1='http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/subscribe/manage/v1_0/local'>
         <ns1:subscribeProductRsp>
            <result>22007233</result>
            <resultDescription>Temporary Order saved successfully! DataSendStep finish end.</resultDescription>
         </ns1:subscribeProductRsp>
      </ns1:subscribeProductResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here are my Java Pojo Classes

```
@XmlRootElement (name="subscribeProductResponse",namespace="http://www.csapi.org/schema/parlayx/subscribe/manage/v1_0/local")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SubscribeProductResponse {
//  @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="subscribeProductRsp")
    private SubscribeProductRsp subscribeProductRsp;

    public SubscribeProductRsp getSubscribeProductRsp() {
        return subscribeProductRsp;
    }

        public void setSubscribeProductRsp(SubscribeProductRsp subscribeProductRsp) {
        this.subscribeProductRsp = subscribeProductRsp;
    }



}
```

---

```
@XmlRootElement(name="subscribeProductRsp")
public class SubscribeProductRsp {

    private String result;

    private String resultDescription;

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "result", required = true)
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getResultDescription() {
        return resultDescription;
    }
    @XmlElement(name = "resultDescription", required = true)
    public void setResultDescription(String resultDescription) {
        this.resultDescription = resultDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ClassPojo [result = " + result + ", resultDescription = "
                + resultDescription + "]";
    }
}
```

Below is the code to unmarshal the response message

```
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SubscribeProductResponse.class);
       Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
       SubscribeProductResponse output = (SubscribeProductResponse)um.unmarshal(soapResponse.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

       System.out.println(output.getSubscribeProductRsp().getResult());

    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SubscribeProductResponse.class);
   Unmarshaller um = jc.createUnmarshaller();
   SubscribeProductResponse output = (SubscribeProductResponse)um.unmarshal(soapResponse.getSOAPBody().extractContentAsDocument());

   System.out.println(output.getSubscribeProductRsp().getResult());
```

I am getting output.getSubscribeProductRsp() as null

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever solve this @kirti? I'm having a similar problem now... Thx